# Display form value in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to display a forms preset value in a div while also displaying the users new input?

The last one I got to work with this code:

```
<div class='printchatbox' id='printchatbox'></div>
<input type='text' name='fname' value="Kees" class='chatinput' id='chatinput'>
```

**JS :**

```
var inputBox = document.getElementById('chatinput');

inputBox.onkeyup = function(){
    document.getElementById('printchatbox').innerHTML = inputBox.value;
}
```

But for some forms the value is already set and I need them to be displayed aswell.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to call `document.getElementById('printchatbox').innerHTML = inputBox.value;` outside of the function, https://jsfiddle.net/s6632p9a/

Comment: I'm sorry, currently developing in PHP/SQL mainly. Haven't had the time to read into javascript, jQuery, ajax etc. Just needed this for my application for a school project which should be finished soon after the holidays.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Firstly use jQuery because you should.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

#### The HTML

```
<input type="text" name="my_input" id="my_input" value="">

<div id="current_value">
    <!-- We'll put the value here -->
</div>
```

#### The JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Check current set value and update div HTML
    $( document ).ready( function() {

        $('#current_value').html($('#my_input').val());

    });

    // On change, update the div HTML
    $( document ).on('keyup', '#my_input', function() {

        $('#current_value').html($(this).val());

    });

</script>
```

That should do it for you - here's the codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yeVQVe

Comment: @Braatan _But for some forms the value is already set and I need them to be displayed aswell._, this will not do the trick!!!?? i can't see why this answer in marked as accepted!

Answer (score 0):

> But for some forms the value is already set and I need them to be displayed aswel

You should add :

```
document.getElementById('printchatbox').innerHTML = inputBox.value;
```

Before `onkeyup` event.

---

```js
var inputBox = document.getElementById('chatinput');
document.getElementById('printchatbox').innerHTML = inputBox.value;

inputBox.onkeyup = function(){
    document.getElementById('printchatbox').innerHTML = inputBox.value;
}
```

```html
<div class='printchatbox' id='printchatbox'></div>
<input type='text' name='fname' value="Kees" class='chatinput' id='chatinput'>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like following. Just add `document.getElementById('printchatbox').innerHTML = inputBox.value` this line directly in script tag.

```
<div class='printchatbox' id='printchatbox'></div>
<input type='text' name='fname' value="Kees" class='chatinput' id='chatinput'>

<script>
    var inputBox = document.getElementById('chatinput');

    inputBox.onkeyup = function () {
        document.getElementById('printchatbox').innerHTML = inputBox.value;
    }

    document.getElementById('printchatbox').innerHTML = inputBox.value;
</script>
```